# React Context and Storybook: Changing value of a React Context inside a component story

Tags: reactjs, react-context, storybook

I'm wondering how I would go about changing the value of a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) inside a component story in Storybook.
I imagine there is a way to control this via the Story Controls, but there isn't any documentation on it.

I used [this part](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators#context-for-mocking) of the Storybook documentation to provide my Stories with two seperate Contexts.

My code in `.storybook/preview.js` looks like this:

```
export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <FilterProvider>
      <SearchQueryProvider>
        <Story />
      </SearchQueryProvider>
    </FilterProvider>
  ),
];
```

The `FilterProvider` and `SearchQueryProvider` code looks like this:

```
const SearchQueryProvider = ({ children }: SearchQueryProviderProps) => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    <SearchQueryContext.Provider value={[searchQuery, setSearchQuery]}>
      {children}
    </SearchQueryContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { SearchQueryProvider, useSearchQuery };
```

The initial values of these states are basically empty.
To test and preview my components which consume these Contexts I would now like to change the values inside Storybook.

If anyone has an idea how I could achieve this: I'd be delighted to know and grateful for you sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `initialValue` as property and set the initial value of the `searchQuery` state and use `""` as default:

```
const SearchQueryProvider = ({ children, initialValue = "" }: SearchQueryProviderProps) => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>(initialValue);

  return (
    <SearchQueryContext.Provider value={[searchQuery, setSearchQuery]}>
      {children}
    </SearchQueryContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { SearchQueryProvider, useSearchQuery };
```

This allows you to use your Provider like this:

```
export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <FilterProvider>
      <SearchQueryProvider initialValue="something">
        <Story />
      </SearchQueryProvider>
    </FilterProvider>
  ),
];
```

Comment: That works as far as I can set the value and it shows in the story.
But I can't set this value in the Controls panel of a component story.

Comment: If you set the initial value of your provider, I don't think that you can change it in the control panel. But you could do this to control the value (sorry, the format is messed up):

```jsx
const Template = ({ searchQuery, ...args }) => (
  <SearchQueryContext.Provider value={[searchQuery]}>
    <SearchComponent {...args} />
  </SearchQueryProvider>
);

export const WithProvider= Template.bind({});

WithProvider.args = {
  searchQuery: "",
  otherProperty: "with some value"
};
```

If you use the control panel, the `SearchComponent` won't be able to change the value anymore.